# How to implement matchForInvite?

Tags: swift, game-center

sorry bros another stupid question from me.
I was trying to implement the "invitehandler" for a simple multi-player game I am working on. I checked the apple website and it seems that the invitehandler is being replaced by "matchforinvite". I tried to do this like the following and it doesnt work. Can anyone help me a bit here?

```
 GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().matchForInvite(invite, completionHandler: { (match: GKMatch!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if error != nil {
// error out
}
if match != nil {
// success 
}
})
```

Comment: hello, thanks for all the attempts to help me out. Lemme try to add some more info here. I checked the documentation and it said we should never create GKInvite object by ourselves instead, it will be generated by the system when we receive an invite. Therefore I dont know how could I invoke this handler without creating an object. Cause the GKInvite object only exists in runtime... https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchmaker_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMatchmaker/matchForInvite:completionHandler:

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code in a Playground with **import GameKit** and after receiving an error I deleted all code from the right until matchForInvite. Then I typed "(" and was given the following call:

```
GKMatchmaker.sharedMatchmaker().matchForInvite(invite: GKInvite!, completionHandler: ((GKMatch!, NSError!) -> Void)! )
```

I suppose you forgot to write the identifier of the **GKInvite!** object you are asked to pass to the method (unless the *invite* label can be omitted and your object is really called **invite**, but I'm just guessing since I've never used GameKit myself).

Comment: hello, thanks for all the attempts to help me out. Lemme try to add some more info here. I checked the documentation and it said we should never create GKInvite object by ourselves instead, it will be generated by the system when we receive an invite. Therefore I dont know how could I invoke this handler without creating an object. Cause the GKInvite object only exists in runtime...